# Django- Duplicated queries in nested models querying with ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-mptt

How do I get rid of the duplicated queries as in the screenshot?

[image]

---

I have two models as following,

```
class Genre(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
                             blank=True, related_name='children')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, blank=True, related_name='games')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and have a serializer and views,

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        exclude = ['genre', ]


class GenreGameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = RecursiveField(many=True)
    games = GameSerializer(many=True,)

    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'children', 'games']


class GamesByGenreAPI(APIView):
    queryset = Genre.objects.root_nodes()
    serializer_class = GenreGameSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ser = GenreGameSerializer(data=Genre.objects.root_nodes()
                                      .prefetch_related('children__children', 'games'), many=True)
        if ser.is_valid():
            pass
        return Response(ser.data)
```

so basically the model populated when serialized looks like this
[image]

The result is what I am expecting but there are n duplicated queries for each of the genre. How can I fix it? Thanks..

> here is a paste https://pastebin.com/xfRdBaF4 with all code, if you want to reproduce the issue.
>  Also add `path('games/', GamesByGenreAPI.as_view()),` in urls.py which is omitted in paste.

#### Update

tried logging queries to check if its issue with debug toolbar, but it is NOT, the queries are duplicated.. here is the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I think is  an issue on the debug toolbar. I had similar problems, repeated queries and very slow performance, high cpu usage... Finally, I removed the debug toolbar and checked the queries directly in the mysql logs. It was good. Non-repeated queries, fast responses...

Comment: @Tonio in my case its duplicated in postgres too..

Comment: I think your queries are fine, they are quite similar but not the same. Your time-price to get best performance will probably be much higer than the consumed resources (cpu, memory) by these queries.

Comment: ```prefetch_related('children__children')```, why not just ```children``` in prefetch_related? 
[prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From debug toolbar output I will asume that you have two level of nesting in your Genre model (root, Level 1). I do not know if the Level 1 has any children, i.e. there are Level 2 genres, since I can't view the query results (but this is not relevant for the current problem).

The root level Genres are (1, 4, 7), the Level 1 are (2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9).
The prefetch worked for these lookups `prefetch_related("children__children")` as the queries are grouped in two separate queries, as it should be.

The next query for games related to root level genres (`prefetch_related("games")`) are also prefetched. It is the fourth query in the debug toolbar output.

The next queries as you can see are getting the games for each of Level 1 genres in a separate query, which I presume are triggered from the serialiser fields, since there are no lookups specified in the view, that could prefetch those records. Adding another prefetch lookup targeted at those records should solve the problem.

```
ser = GenreGameSerializer(data=Genre.objects.root_nodes()
                                    .prefetch_related(
                                        'children__children', 
                                        'games'
                                        # prefetching games for Level 1 genres 
                                        'children__games'),       
                          many=True)
```

Note, that if there are more nested genres, the same logic should be applied for each nesting level. For example, if there are Level 2 genres, then you should prefetch the related games for those genres with:

```
ser = GenreGameSerializer(data=Genre.objects.root_nodes()
                                    .prefetch_related(
                                        'children__children', 
                                        'games'
                                        'children__games',
                                        'children__children__games'), 
                          many=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach on how to overcome the multiple queries being made.

```
from collections import defaultdict

from rest_framework.serializers import SerializerMethodField


class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        exclude = ['genre', ]


class GenreGameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = SerializerMethodField(source='get_children')
    games = GameSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'games']
    
    def get_children(self, obj):
        # get genre childrens from context and pass it to same serializer
        # no extra queries are done, since we alredy have the instances
        children = self.context['children'].get(obj.id, [])
        serializer = GenreGameSerializer(children, many=True, context=self.context)
        return serializer.data


class GamesByGenreAPI(APIView):
    queryset = Genre.objects.root_nodes()
    serializer_class = GenreGameSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # gather genres from queryset class attribute and prefetch games
        genres = self.get_queryset().prefetch_related('games')

        # gather all descendants of root nodes and prefetch games
        genre_descendants = genres.get_descendants().prefetch_related('games')
        
        # create a dictionary with key parent and value list of children
        # this will not require extra queries
        children_dict = defaultdict(list)
        for descendant in descendants:
            children_dict[descendant.parent_id].append(descendant)
        
        # add the dictionary as context for serializer
        context = self.get_serializer_context()
        context['children'] = children_dict
        
        # send the context to serializer    
        ser = GenreGameSerializer(data=genres, context=context, many=True)
        return Response(ser.data)
```

The `GamesByGenreAPI` class can be written nicer, by overriding `self.get_queryset()` and `self.get_serializer_context()` but I tried to keep it in one method for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The `prefetch_related` only works on the root level tree, because it is only specified in that query. Subsequent child's obtained by a new query generated with `RecursiveField` do not have these related objects *pre-fetched*. Probably you can overwrite the queries in the  `RecursiveField`, but I think it runs a separate new query on each attribute of `childrens` found.

Well, if you wants to reduce the queries to only 3, you would need get all the data from the models and manually build the output array in a recursive way.

This is a very dirty code, you lose the "Django's magic", and as in the comment, I think it is a waste of time in most scenarios.

```py
class GamesByGenreAPI(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        games = {}
        for g in Game.objects.all():
            games[g.pk] = {
                'id': g.id,
                'name': g.name
            }

        TreeGame = Game.genre.through
        tree_game = {}
        for tg in TreeGame.objects.all():
            if tg.genre_id not in tree_game:
                tree_game[tg.genre_id] = []
            tree_game[tg.genre_id].append(tg.game_id)

        childrens = {}
        roots = []
        for g in Genre.objects.all():
            if g.level == 0:
                roots.append(g)
            else:
                if g.parent_id not in childrens:
                    childrens[g.parent_id] = []
                childrens[g.parent_id].append(g)

        def _get_data_from_tree_branch(game):
            branch_data = {
                'id': game.pk,
                'name': game.name
            }
            if game.pk in childrens:
                # Move up if you need a children array in every response
                branch_data['children'] = []
                for c in childrens[game.pk]:
                    branch_data['children'].append(
                        _get_data_from_tree_branch(c)
                    )
            if game.pk in tree_game:
                # Move up if you need a games array in every response
                branch_data['games'] = []
                for rel in tree_game[game.pk]:
                    branch_data['games'].append(games[rel])

            return branch_data
    
        data = []
        for g in roots:
            data.append(_get_data_from_tree_branch(g))
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: kind of verbose solution. The accepted answer does the job without sacrificing the "Django's magic", thank you for your effort.

Comment: No problem. Thank you @Rivadiz.

Answer (score 2):

You missed `children__games` relation in `prefetch_related()`. It will work if you replace

```
prefetch_related('children__children', 'games')
```

with

```
prefetch_related('children__children', 'children__games', 'games')
```

[Here is request list at Django debug panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PDlV.png)